# Select2 V4: How to modify selected item after the user selecte it

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

When user select an item from Select2 V4 component, the component shows it and user could not change this value. If user wants to modify active item and enter modified text, the Select2 assumes that it is a new value and adds it to the list. It is bad. How to change current active value and put it into selected item?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is listen for the `select2:selecting` event:

```
$('#mySelect').on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

In your event handler you'll be able to remove the added item (or prevent it from being added...I haven't tried this myself) and change the user's selection.  See https://select2.github.io/examples.html#events

A word of caution: what you want to do is not standard behavior for a select box. A standard HTML `select` jumps to the next `option` beginning with the letter the user typed.  If you were to change that behavior you may find yourself with many unhappy users (see the [principle of least surprise/astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).

Comment: What I want to do is to select predefined items from a list and to modify them, if they are contain errors. It's a mix of two standards: `select` and `input`. Let's imagine the situation. In web-system many users use Select2 to pick and add data. One of them makes an error and that value stored in DB. Another user chooses that value. Another one has seen that it contains error and modify it. Such as it is a global modification, now data of all other users is correct. @Pauld, do you know how to realize that interface using as small elements as possible?

Comment: Maybe you could have a button to explicitly put the UI into edit mode - that way the user's intent is clear when editing and there are no unintended edits.

Comment: Yes I think about that, but delay and try to find another way.